# Which subset of html does WordPress support?

Tags: plugin-development, html, html-editor

I am in the middle of writing plugin for WordPress which would cross-post articles from wordpress to different places.

I need to know what html-code can be produced by wordpress editor... or in general which subset of html is supported by wordpress.

Is there any official document about that? Maybe my question is just wrong, and WordPress supports full html5, so in such case my question would be only about code which can be produced by editor.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress supports all html imaginable. Actually, WP can produce html that is invalid or totally non-existent. Even better, you can have WP produce total gibberish if you want to, or a nasty piece of malware, or code that would only run on a 70s Unix machine. And yes, all of this can be typed in the editor.

Because WP essentially glues strings of characters from the database, templates and plugins together and sends it to the browser, no matter what these strings contain.